# Grid или Flex? Кто лучше?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox, css-grid

Пользуюсь активно `flex`, все задачи с ним решаю при верстке.

Но много кто говорит, что `grid` это наше будущее.

Так ли он хорош, и что лучше использовать?

Comment: Все зависит от задачи, гриды позволяют работать как по горизонтали так и по вертикали. Гриды удобней использовать для раскладки основных блоков, а для остального `flex`.

Comment: По мне, grid- это тот же html-grid, только на CSS. То есть представляешь таблицу и объединяешь несколько колонок в одну, несколько строк в одну, во флексе с этим дела потруднее.

Comment: Т.е. большие блоки на сайте стоит размещать на гриде, а внутри них на флексе?

Comment: Это не является обязательным, нужно делать так как вам удобней и того требует задача. Сайты можно полностью сделать на `flex` или `grid`, но есть ситуации когда проще воспользоваться конкретным инструментом.
По [ссылке](https://codepen.io/AFI/pen/eGjXbL) есть пример который я делал на `bootstrap`(т.е. на `flex`),а на гридах его можно было бы сделать за пару строк кода и с меньшим количеством `html`.

Comment: Можете показать пример этого же только на гридах?

Comment: Все верно говорят, зависит от задачи, но хочу добавить, что поддержка гридов сейчас 88% в то время как flex 95, поэтому без особой необходимости в гридах, прекрасно можно обойтись флексами. Думаю где-то через год уже можно будет комбинировать их без оглядки на старые браузеры, как это было с флексами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависимо от задачи. Например, если нужно спроектировать React-компоненты для позиционирования дочерних элементов, то следует использовать Grid: Как в Chrome, так и в Safari используется движок отображения webkit и он плохо дружит с flex...

[image: chrome-flex-bug]

В этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991662/100-height-when-parent-is-flex-item-chrome-bug) можно посмотреть код, корректно отображающийся в FireFox и не работающий в Chrome. Вопрос был задан в 2015 и до сих пор не закрыт!

Тем не менее, если вложенных flex-контейнеров не предвидится, их тоже можно использовать...